# How do I remove an item from a subscription created by Woocommerce Subscriptions with a hook in php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using Woocommerce Subscriptions to create my subscription products.
I have a use case where I need to change a product in a newly created subscription with a different product.
To achieve this, my plan is to remove the "old" product from the subscription, and. add the "new" product to the subscription.

I have attempted to remove the "old" product from a newly created subscription with a callback function on the woocommerce_subscription_status_pending_to_active action hook, but it keeps looping until the Allowed memory size is exhausted.

This is my callback function:

```php
/**
 * Triggered when a subscription status is changed from pending to active.
 *
 * @since 2.2.22
 * @param WC_Subscription $subscription
 */

function action_activated_subscription( $subscription ) {

    error_log('Hi before doing foreach subscription');

    foreach( $subscription->get_items() as $item_id => $subscription_item ){
        $product_id = $subscription_item['product_id'];
        $subscription_item_id = $subscription_item['id'];
        error_log('test product ID is: ' . $product_id);
        if ($product_id === 3913) {
            error_log('Remove item!');           
            $subscription->remove_item($subscription_item_id);
            // Update totals.
            error_log('Calculating totals.');   
            $subscription->calculate_totals();
            error_log('Saving subscription.');   
            $subscription->save();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_pending_to_active', 'action_activated_subscription', 20, 1 );
```

This is my error log, representing the continuous loop which ends with a fatal error:

```bash
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Hi before doing foreach subscription
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] test product ID is: 3873
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] test product ID is: 3913
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Remove item!
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Calculating totals.
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Hi before doing foreach subscription
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] test product ID is: 3873
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] test product ID is: 3913
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Remove item!
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Calculating totals.
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Hi before doing foreach subscription
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] test product ID is: 3873
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] test product ID is: 3913
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Remove item!
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Calculating totals.
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Hi before doing foreach subscription
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] test product ID is: 3873
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] test product ID is: 3913
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Remove item!
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Calculating totals.
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Hi before doing foreach subscription
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] test product ID is: 3873
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] test product ID is: 3913
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Remove item!
[01-Aug-2022 21:41:45 UTC] Calculating totals.
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] Hi before doing foreach subscription
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] test product ID is: 3873
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] test product ID is: 3913
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] Remove item!
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] Calculating totals.
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] Hi before doing foreach subscription
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] test product ID is: 3873
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] test product ID is: 3913
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] Remove item!
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] Calculating totals.
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] Hi before doing foreach subscription
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] test product ID is: 3873
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] test product ID is: 3913
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] Remove item!
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] Calculating totals.
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /usr/local/lsws/tuttelue/html/wp-includes/meta.php on line 1198
[01-Aug-2022 21:42:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /usr/local/lsws/tuttelue/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 265
```

How can I remove an item from a subscription successfully?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the $subscription->calculate_totals(); line is preventing the loop from reaching the end, and it seems to be restarting, because we never see 'Saving subscription.' in the log file. I think the calculate_totals() function is changing the array from within the loop and that's messing things up.

Maybe move calculate_totals() and save() outside the foreach loop to the end.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33941612)

Comment: Please insert full code of your solution and try to format the text better by using the tools of the textarea